# How can I have more than 10 marker types in a scatter plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, scatter-plot

The documentation specifies only 10 types of markers in a scatter plot:
http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html

I need 30. My current string for marker types is:

```
markers = '+o*.xsd^v<>h';
```

I don't want to reuse the same markers. Entering other letters etc. results in a crash. Letters of the alphabet would be acceptable markers. Is there a way to have more than 10 types of markers?

Edit: I'm already using colors to indicate something else.

Comment: Would different colors be ok? How about filled and not-filled circles, rectangles, ...?

Comment: Apparently, the question ["Can I make a Scatter Plot with Custom Marker Symbols"](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/32985-can-i-make-a-scatterplot-with-custom-marker-symbols) was answered with *no*. That answer dates back to 2012 - but there is no indication that this has changed.

Comment: Filled rectangles and other shapes are undesirable because they are more likely to hide other symbols beneath them. That 2012 link is interesting. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `patch` with defined shape and with defined transparency if you're worried about layering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several function can be used to emulate the behaviour of `scatter`. Here we use both `text` and `plot` to create unique markers.

On the left, markers with numbers and dots, on the right circle and arrows (thanks to unicode).

[image]

Computation:

```
N = 50;
x = rand(N,1);
y = rand(N,1);

%numbers in text
txt1 = cellstr(num2str((11:11+N-1)'));

%unicode text
Nstart = 8592; %arrows 
txt2 = cellstr(char(Nstart:Nstart+N-1)');

figure;
subplot(1,2,1);
h = text(x, y, txt1, ...
    'FontName', 'Courier New', 'FontSize', 18, ...
    'HorizontalAlignment', 'center', 'VerticalAlignment', 'middle');

hold on;
plot(x, y, 'r.', 'MarkerSize', 10)

subplot(1,2,2);
h = text(x, y, txt2, ...
    'FontSize', 20, ...
    'HorizontalAlignment', 'center', 'VerticalAlignment', 'middle');

hold on;
plot(x, y, 'o', 'MarkerSize', 22)
```

Comment: if i have x vector and y vector and i make a scatter plot. how do i give different colours to x and y values

Comment: I would use ´hold on´ with several scatter plot function calls

Answer (score 1):

You can use [text](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) to plot letters at particular locations. It will be much less efficient because each point will require a new graphics object.

Comment: That's interesting. I'll have to rework it quite a lot but this might work. I'll try it. Thanks.